# JQuery EasyUI TreeGrid table column width

Tags: treegrid, jquery-easyui

i am new to jQuery and not sure how this happening,
but i am already mentioned width in data options still getting width=10000px

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#tt').treegrid({     url:'treegrid3_getdata.php',
                                    animate: true,
                                    idField:'id',
                                    treeField:'name',
                                    columns:[[      {title:'Folder Name',field:'name',width:180},  
                                                    {field:'description',title:'description',width:100},
                                                    {field:'level',title:'Level',width:80},
                                                    {field:'created',title:'Created',width:80}
                                            ]]
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: check your css. also, post the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the option `fitColumns` for the grid to true somewhere in your code? This would override the width specified for the columns and expand the table to the width of the container.

**Disclaimer:** I don't seem to have enough reputation to post this as a comment to the original question, or I can't figure how to do so. Apologies.